# Trigger Java JAR to run with C++ and pass a String

Tags: java, c++, jar

Lets imagine I have the following two very simple code snippets in C++ and Java:

**C++**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
string str = "Hello Java from C++";
cout << str << endl;

When reaching here, while running this C++ program, I would like to trigger the program to run my JAR and send str as a argument so the Java program can take it and set it as a String.

return 0; 
}
```

**Java**

```
public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = argumentFromJAR; //take argument from the JAR and set it as a String
    System.out.println("Got" + str + "from the C++ program");
}
}
```

When executing the C++ program, I want it to run a JAR-file and pass it as String as an argument. The JAR is already created and somehow I want to get this String to end up in Java.

I would be happy for your help! And oh, btw, I will run the C++ program with g++ on CentOS if that matters (Java is also installed and tested).

Comment: `int result = system("/path/to/java -jar /path/to/jarfile [args...]");` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the jar using this line: `system("java filename.jar [args]");`

Also in the java file you have to do something like this:

```
String str = "";
for(int i = 0; i<args.length;i++) str += args[i]; 
System.out.println("Got" + str + "from the C++ program");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Jake Freeman was basically right. However, I have two little things that should be changed in the snippets of code:

1. Do not call "java" if you are not sure that the environment variable
   of the same name actually points to the Java directory. Otherwise,
   use the full path to your desired JRE java.exe. However, this will
   make your program less flexible if you want it to be run by other
   users, as they will not be able to customize the path (perhaps only
   via a configuration file?).
2. The proposed for-loop destroys any spaces that normally
   separate the arguments in the command line. So here's a suggestion
   that kepps the separating spaces and makes all arguments pass into a
   String:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       String argumentString = "";
       for(int i = 0; i < args.length(); i++) {
           argumentString += args[i] + " ";
       }
       argumentString = argumentString.trim();

       System.out.println("Got " + argumentString + " from the C++ program");
   }
   ```